# Debug: Couldn't match expected type ‘GHC.Types.Bool’ with actual type ‘Bool’

Tags: debugging, haskell, lambda, case, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to resolve the following exercise of Haskell:

Define the function `exists::(N-> Bool)-> N->Bool`, which receives a predicate p and a natural n, and returns True if there is any number between O and n for which p is true.
Examples:

```
exists pair three = True
exists isGreaterThanZero O = False
```

This code goes before of my exists function:

```
{-#LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-tabs #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-missing-methods #-}

module Naturales where

import Prelude(Show)

data Bool where {   False :: Bool; 
                    True :: Bool
                } deriving Show

{- Data Type of Natural Numbers -}
data N where { O :: N ; 
               S :: N -> N 
            } deriving Show
    
    zero:: N
    zero= O
    
    one:: N
    one = S O
    
    two :: N
    two = S one 
    
    three :: N
    three = S two 
    
    four :: N
    four = S three
    ...
```

This is how I programmed the requested function called exists but when i try to compile the .hs code it
says

```
exists:: (N->Bool)->N->Bool
exists = \p -> \x -> case x of {
            O -> p O;
            (S y) -> if p (S y) then True else existe p y; {- Line 288 -}
        }


    • Couldn't match expected type ‘GHC.Types.Bool’
                  with actual type ‘Bool’
      NB: ‘Bool’ is defined at EstudiandoRecursion.hs:(9,1)-(11,47)
          ‘GHC.Types.Bool’
            is defined in ‘GHC.Types’ in package ‘ghc-prim-0.5.3’
    • In the expression: p (S y)
      In the expression: if p (S y) then True else existe p y
      In a case alternative:
          (S y) -> if p (S y) then True else existe p y
    |
288 |                         (S y) -> if p (S y) then True else existe p y;     |
```

I suppose that the logic of my function exists it's correct, but perhaps I have made syntax error writing the code.

Comment: It seems you defined a `Bool` type in your code, and thus no longer refer to the `Bool` of `GHC.Types.Bool`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I have updated the description of my question, adding my header code which is before of the exists function

Comment: Well `if ... ` expects a `Bool` of the builtin type, so `True`/`False` from your type will *not* suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have redefined the standard `Bool` type. Haskell does not know that your own redefined type is actually the same as the standard one, so it treats them as two separate types: `Bool` (yours), and `GHC.Types.Bool` (the standard one).

The `if cond then t else e` expression only works with the standard `Bool` type, not your custom one. Hence, you can't use it in

```
if p (S y) then True else exists p y
```

since `p (S y)` returns your own custom `Bool`. Consider instead

```
case p (S y) of
   True  -> True
   False -> exists p y
```

which, unlike `if`, should work, picking the right `True` and `False` constructors from you new type. You can use `case .. of { .. ; ... }` if you prefer braces and semicolons.

Answer (score 4):

You are making use of a `if … then … else …` expression. This requires the condition to be of type `Bool`, and this is the *builtin* `Bool`, so defining your own `Bool` type will not suffice.

It is however sufficient to work with a `case … of …` clause and thus pattern match on your `True`/`False` data constructors:

```
exists:: (N -> Bool) -> N -> Bool
exists = \p -> \x -> case x of {
            O -> p O;
            (S y) -> case p (S y) of
                True -> True
                _ -> exists p y
        }
```